# Python program is running even after the files are removed

Tags: python

It should sound stupid. But here is my scenario.

I have a **python-flask** website which is made live using `nohup`. Now even after i removed all files in `__pycache__` and the original `.py` files the program is still running without any errors. So where does it run from ? Is there any cache of files getting created anywhere else?

Note: I know i can kill the process but just wanted to know about this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as one process has a file open, the file will remain available to that process. No other processes can open it, and its existence will not be visible with normal OS utilities, such as `ls`.

In the case of Python, I think that the compiled version of the script remains in memory. Removing it from the filesystem does nothing to change that.

So your flask app is not affected until it terminates, at which point the resident memory will be freed and any files that it held open will be removed by the OS.

Comment: hi @mhawke . So I have around 10 .py files associated with the program. So does this mean all the bytecode (.pyc) files associated with the program are all loaded to memory for the time the process is running?

Comment: @kten:  I believe so, yes, memory permitting. If the files are large they might be swapped out to disk, but the OS will manage this separately from the original files.

Answer (score 1):

> So where does it run from ?

It runs from memory. Once your program has been compiled to byte code (or the byte code has been loaded from `.pyc` files), it is shipped off for execution to the Python Virtual Machine and the original source file is closed. Removing it doesn't affect the running process.